# Trying to fire a method in code behind on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET project, I have a button that I want to fire a method in code behind to update database with updated client data when clicked.

This is my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="submitChanges_OnClick" Text="Submit" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void submitChanges_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here
}
```

On page load I get this **error message:**

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.account_heatingcontrols_aspx' does not contain a
definition for 'submitChanges_OnClick' and no extension method 'submitChanges_OnClick' 
accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.account_heatingcontrols_aspx' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here, I have googled, but no luck.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `private` to `protected`.

```
protected void submitChanges_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```